# jQuery Multiple toggles with show/hide text change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Long time lurker first time asker! 
This is my first question so apologies if I'm asking incorrectly!

I couldn't seem to find an already asked question for this.

I want to have multiple toggles that work independently from each other.

I've picked up the code for this from another thread [Jquery - How to have multiple toggle on one page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171714/jquery-how-to-have-multiple-toggle-on-one-page) I don't totally understand why this works (but it works quite well) however I want to change the displayed text on the expanded toggle from 'show' to 'hide' once clicked.

I have managed to make this work with only one toggle but with multiple toggles it doesn't work. I've mashed together code from the two and I am probably missing something really obvious.

I can't seem to work this out, both change at the same time, I want them to change independently without having to create multiple functions with different names.

I am a complete novice with javascript/jQuery so I'm probably missing something really obvious, or it might not be possible at all, but your help would be much appreciated!

Here is the code I have so far:

HTML

```
<div>
 <p><a class="toggle-trigger">Show</a><span>list 1</span><p>
 <div class="toggle-wrap">
  <div class="style-single">
   <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>

<p><a class="toggle-trigger">Show</a><span>list 2</span><p>
<div class="toggle-wrap">
 <div class="style-single">
   <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

jQuery

```
    $(".toggle-trigger").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().nextAll('.toggle-wrap').first().slideToggle();

                    var txt = $('.toggle-trigger').html();

            if (txt == 'hide'){
                    $('.toggle-trigger').html('show');
            } else {
                    $('.toggle-trigger').html('hide');
            }


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `$(this)` to point to current element. Using Class selector points to all elements with same class again

change the script as shown below and it should work as expected. You don't have to make any change in the HTML

```
    $(".toggle-trigger").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().nextAll('.toggle-wrap').first().slideToggle();

        var txt = $(this).html();

        if (txt == 'hide'){
                $(this).html('show');
        } else {
                $(this).html('hide');
        }
    });
```

Comment: It would be better to use conditional operator instead of If - else, where possible.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot a closing div. You also cant use the same function on a identical selector. Also, you text is the exact oposite of what you want to have, this can be confusing.

Try this: (**EDIT:** made the code more readable)

```js
$(".toggle-trigger").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().nextAll('.toggle-wrap').first().slideToggle();

            var txt = $('.toggle-trigger').html();

            if (txt == 'Hide '){
                    $('.toggle-trigger').html('Show ');
            } else {
                    $('.toggle-trigger').html('Hide ');
            }


});


$(".toggle-trigger-2").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().nextAll('.toggle-wrap').first().slideToggle();

        var txt = $('.toggle-trigger-2').html();

        if (txt == 'Hide '){
                $('.toggle-trigger').html('Show ');
        } else {
                $('.toggle-trigger').html('Hide ');
        }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p><a class="toggle-trigger" style="color: blue; ">Show </a><span>list 1</span><p>
  <div class="toggle-wrap">
      <div class="style-single">
         <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>4</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <p><a class="toggle-trigger-2" style="color: blue; ">Show </a><span>list 2</span><p>
    <div class="toggle-wrap">
       <div class="style-single">
           <ul>
              <li>1</li>
              <li>2</li>
              <li>3</li>
              <li>4</li>
           </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've picked up the code for this from another thread Jquery - How to have multiple toggle on one page? I don't totally understand why this works (but it works quite well)

```
$(this).parent().nextAll('.toggle-wrap').first().slideToggle()
```

Means

- I get the clicked element (`.toggle-trigger`)
- Go to its parent (`p`)
- Get all parent's next siblings
- Take the first (`.toggle-wrap`)
- Does `slideToggle()` on it

As said in previous answers, your problem is you are changing text for all elements with `.toggle-trigger` class.

I used a different approach to solve it. I created a parent `div` for each list to toggle. Also, I used a callback function on the `slideToggle()` call, to make the `.toggle-trigger` text change once the `slideToggle()` has finished. You can try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/57025Lco/